# Can I run raspberry pi pico software on a pi 3B?

Tags: pi-3, pi-pico, compatibility

So in this video he uses a pico to automatically rickroll someone. Can I just follow the same steps?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_f9p-_JWZw

And there's a different guide for the same prank, but it was designed for a pi zero. Would that work, if the other doesn't?
https://github.com/ossiozac/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Duckberry-Pi

Edit: Okay, someone answered

Comment: I'd use the raspberry pi guide for raspberry pi, pico guide for pico

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pico software only works on the Raspberry Pico microcontroller.

Raspberry Pi software works on all models of the Raspberry Pi computers. E.g. Pi A, Pi B, Pi B+, Pi 2B, Pi 3B, Pi 3B+, Pi Zero, Pi Zero W, Pi 4B, Pi 400, Pi Compute Modules etc.